# Why the attack's ip address has a string 'dia'

Tags: networking, security

This is a record from `netstat –lnt | grep ^tcp`:

```
tcp        0      0 xx.xxx.xx.72:ssh        106.49.174.61.dia:55983 ESTABLISHED
```

"x" is hidden by me :)

my questions are:

- why does the address have a 'dia'?
- Has he already logged in my ubuntu server by sshd?
- How to ban this address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ip address, `106.49.174.61`, belongs [CHINACACHE](http://www.chinacache.com/index_1.html).

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ whois 106.49.174.61
% [whois.apnic.net]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

% Information related to '106.48.0.0 - 106.49.255.255'

inetnum:        106.48.0.0 - 106.49.255.255
netname:        CHINACACHE
descr:          Beijing Blue I.T Technologies Co.,Ltd.
descr:          Galaxy Building,No.10 jiuxianqiao ,chaoyang
descr:          District,beijing
country:        CN
admin-c:        YS1150-AP
tech-c:         DC1032-AP
mnt-by:         MAINT-CNNIC-AP
mnt-lower:      MAINT-CNNIC-AP
mnt-routes:     MAINT-CNNIC-AP
mnt-irt:        IRT-CNNIC-CN
status:         ALLOCATED PORTABLE
changed:        hm-changed@apnic.net 20110322
source:         APNIC

irt:            IRT-CNNIC-CN
address:        Beijing, China
e-mail:         ipas@cnnic.cn
abuse-mailbox:  ipas@cnnic.cn
admin-c:        IP50-AP
tech-c:         IP50-AP
auth:           # Filtered
remarks:        Please note that CNNIC is not an ISP and is not
remarks:        empowered to investigate complaints of network abuse.
remarks:        Please contact the tech-c or admin-c of the network.
mnt-by:         MAINT-CNNIC-AP
changed:        ipas@cnnic.cn 20110428
source:         APNIC
```

CHINACACHE is ISP and in most cases sufix `dia` mean **D**ynamic **I**p **A**ddress. ISP uses large public ip address pools for users of ISP services [adsl, 3g, wless ... ].

First you must disconnect this ip.

`netstat -ntp` will give you a `PID` of process witch you can kill

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ netstat -ntp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53118         127.0.0.1:27117         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:39049      xx.xxx.xx.xxx:443       ESTABLISHED 13261/chrome    
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.x:39048      xx.xxx.xx.xxx:443       ESTABLISHED 13261/chrome
```

*For example you can see two process from my pc witch im make `chrome`*

For killing process aka disconnecting you can use

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Now you must prevent unwelcome connection to you pc. Start firewall.

```
sudo ufw start
```

When start firewall all connection to pc will be prohibited. If you wish to allow access from specific ip on net range you can use this *template* of command to make you rule.

```
ufw [--dry-run] [delete] [insert NUM]  allow|deny|reject|limit  [in|out
       on INTERFACE] [log|log-all] [proto protocol] [from ADDRESS [port PORT]]
       [to ADDRESS [port PORT]]
```

Example

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xx.x port 22 to yyy.yyy.yy.y port 22
```

This rule allow access from `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to your pc on address `yyy.yyy.yy.y` on port `22` witch is for `ssh`

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xx.0/24 port 80 to xxx.xxx.xx.x port 80
```

This rule allow subnet `xxx.xxx.xx.0` with network mask `255.255.255.0` access to your pc on port `80` aka `http` traffic